# the best structure for a forum oop mvc with php?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I am developing a forum in php oop in mvc , but I got a question this is my structure, so where do I must write the set and get methods of each model?, I begin to put the clasess setgetThread, and setgetReply in the controller but I dont sure, can you give some hints, or clarify me if I am doing a goo practice??, I am new in mvc, and I am trying to understand

**Controller**:
ControllerThread, 
ControllerReply

**Model**:
Thread, 
Reply

**View**:
Formthread, 
FormReply, 
Index

Comment: How can anyone think this is off topic?

Answer (score 1):

This question cant be answered exactly.

It depends on style and convention.

Best practices I know is to "keep your controller as skinny as possible" and have a "fat model" instead.

The Model should contain business logic and should be fully operational, but on an environment independent state. Which means for example, dont process HTML there. Just exchange defined data objects.

The controller is responsible to map all the urls to the right place and everything.

Finally the view transforms the data from the model into a form that the user can view (e.g. HTML).

Sometimes it is convention to exchange only data between view/controller or model/controller. I personally see no reason why not to let the model interact with the controller, it brings big advantages like pre processing of data etc.

So to drill it down to your question:

I *think* your controller should load the model and set the thread.

Then then controller should set the correct view in your presentation layer, which then fetches the posts from the model and dispalys them in a nice form.

Comment: but in each model you will put the set and get methods and the other method liker store in the database?

Comment: models usually communicate directly with the database. it is also common to have an extra resource model behind every model where only the database related functions that fetch and write data are stored. i can also imagine a seperate set of resource models that are not in an 1:1 to models, but that is quite uncommon. resource model fucntinos that are required in different sections of the application are usually tunneled through one model.